# How to add AutoScroll to Scrollview in iOS?

Tags: objective-c, ios, scrollview

I am having Scollview in iOS. In that scrollview I have two **Table Views**.

If the contents of Table view get increased dynamically (by row), then I want to add the **AutoScroll** to the **Scrollview**.

Anybody has any idea about this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What do you mean by AutoScroll? How are the contents increased? By one row each time or by one section?

Comment: These are dynamic contents, one row each time

Comment: `setContentOffset:animated:`?

Comment: @Desdenova thanks for reply. I dnt know how to use it?

Comment: Check the API reference. It is so easy to use.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you this following line to make one time autoscroll.

set x if you want to scroll horizontally, otherwise set y to scroll vertical.

```
[scrollView setContentOffset:CGPointMake(x, y) animated:YES];
```

Comment: Hi Romit, I tried this after loading the view but it is not working. ):

Comment: write above code line in  -(void)viewDidAppear; if you are loding your data at viewDidLoad; because loding data may takes time.

Answer (score 1):

i code like this in the text field....

```
-(BOOL)textFieldShouldBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField
{
    if(textField == expenseAmount)
    {

        [self.expenseScrollview setContentOffset:CGPointMake(0.0,50) animated:YES];
       // [self registerForKeyboardNotifications];
    }
    if(textField == exchangeRate){

        [self.expenseScrollview setContentOffset:CGPointMake(0.0,120) animated:YES];

    }


    return YES;
}
```

by following this idea you implement that in table view increment [at the point u need to set ]

and the thing u need to increase the scroll size means u need to use this....

```
scrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(yourWidth,yourHeight);
```